# Ansible Task for processing json and register variables if json contains a given value

Tags: json, api, ansible

for an Ansible Playbook I need to get some results from an API call to check if an ID already exists.

This should be the procedure:

- If the ID exists a task should update the config with an API put request
- If the ID does not exist it should create the config with an API post request

I had the idea for a solution to check if the JSON in the variable `result` contains a field `"ID:" "output-1"`. If so it sets the value of the variable `id_exists` to `true` which can then be used as a condition in the following tasks.

Unfortunately I have no idea which Ansible module to use to search in JSON and register a variable. Maybe someone can please help me to find a solution?

Ansible Example:

```yaml
- name: "Call API to get JSON data"
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://example.com/api/outputs
    method: get
  register: result

- name: "Debug: Print all IDs"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ result.json | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "items[*].{ID: id}"

## Task: Check if JSON result contains the ID output-1
## DON'T KNOW HOW :(

- name: "Create new config"
    url: https://example.com/api/outputs
    method: post
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "ApiKey {{ api_key }}"
    body_format: json
    body: |
      {
         "id": "output-1",
         "name": "Name",
         "is_default": false,
         "type": "testtype",
         "config_yaml": "verification_mode: advanced"
      }
  when: id_exists == false

- name: "Update existing config"
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://example.com/api/outputs/output-1
    method: put
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "ApiKey {{ api_key }}"
    body_format: json
    body: |
      {
         "name": "New Name",
         "is_default": false,
         "type": "testtype",
         "config_yaml": "verification_mode: advanced"
      }
  when: id_exists == true
```

JSON Example:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "output-1",
      "name": "Output 1",
      "is_default": true,
      "type": "testtype",
      "config_yaml": "verification_mode: basic"
    },
    {
        "id": "output-2",
        "name": "Output 2",
        "is_default": false,
        "type": "testtype",
        "config_yaml": "verification_mode: basic"
      },
    {
      "id": "output-3",
      "name": "Output 3",
      "is_default": false,
      "type": "testtype",
      "config_yaml": "verification_mode: basic"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Then [edit] your question to, at the very least 1) fix your code sample to make it syntactically correct (e.g. for the most obvious with all quotes opened and closed correctly... but check for other errors too) 2) add a sample of the json response you get from your api call in the two cases where the id exists and where it does not. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator: I Updated my question and provided a json example. My question was really a bit messy. My apologies, I hope it is acceptable now.

Comment: Note: Since your declared the body type as json, you do not need to declare the body as a json string. You can simply declare an object in yaml as for the rest of the task. It will be transformed on call.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly the following should meet your expectations. I added a few examples as debug tasks to let you play with the result and make your own decision on how to call your API (which I cannot do myself to run an example)

The following playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Faking a return from you API based on example json (minified for legibility)
    result: {"items":[{"id":"output-1","name":"Output 1","is_default":true,"type":"testtype","config_yaml":"verification_mode: basic"},{"id":"output-2","name":"Output 2","is_default":false,"type":"testtype","config_yaml":"verification_mode: basic"},{"id":"output-3","name":"Output 3","is_default":false,"type":"testtype","config_yaml":"verification_mode: basic"}]}

    # What to find in haystack
    needle_id: output-1

    # Note: yes this will work with a register as well as long as it exists
    # at time you evaluate the var.
    # Note: having a key called `items` forces us to use the bracket notation
    # to disambiguate from the `items()` python function
    existing_id: "{{ result['items'] | selectattr('id', '==', needle_id) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: play a task if id exists
      debug:
        msg: id exists
      when: existing_id | length > 0

    - name: play a task if id does not exist
      debug:
        msg: id does not exist
      when: existing_id | length == 0

    - name: play single tasks which will be smart
      vars:
        debug_text: "{{ 'does not exist' if existing_id | length == 0 else 'exists' }}"
      debug:
        msg: "id {{ debug_text }}"

    - name: show the found entry (or empty if not)
      debug:
        var: existing_id | first | d({})
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook uri.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [play a task if id exists] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "id exists"
}

TASK [play a task if id does not exist] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [play single tasks which will be smart] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "id exists"
}

TASK [show the found entry (or empty if not)] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "existing_id | first | d({})": {
        "config_yaml": "verification_mode: basic",
        "id": "output-1",
        "is_default": true,
        "name": "Output 1",
        "type": "testtype"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply.
It took some time and I was interrupted by other projects and tasks but based on your suggestions I came up with the following solution.

1. Perform an API call to get the required informations and store it in the variable `api_outputs`

```
# File: tasks/main.yaml

- name: "API to get JSON data"
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://example.com/api/outputs
    method: get
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
  register: api_outputs
```

2. Filter the value of the `api_outputs` variable to check if it contains the ID I'm looking for "output-1":

```
# File: vars/main.yaml

check_output_id : |
  "{{ api_outputs |
      community.general.json_query('json.items[*]') |
      selectattr('id', '==', output-1) }}"
```

Results:

- IF the variable `check_output_id` has a **length equal to 0** the ID does not exist
- IF the variable `check_output_id` has a **length greater than 0** the ID output-1 already exists

3.1. Create new config via API call IF the variable `check_output_id` has a length equal to 0:

```
# File: tasks/main.yaml

- name: "API: Create new config"
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://example.com/api/outputs
    method: post
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "ApiKey {{ api_key }}"
    body_format: json
    body: |
      {
         "id": "output-1",
         "name": "Name",
         "is_default": false,
         "type": "testtype",
         "config_yaml": "verification_mode: advanced"
      }
  when: check_output_id | length == 0
```

3.2. Update an existing config via API call IF the variable `check_output_id` has a length greater than 0 using the id "output-1" in the url:

```
# File: tasks/main.yaml

- name: "API: Update existing config"
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://example.com/api/outputs/output-1
    method: put
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "ApiKey {{ api_key }}"
    body_format: json
    body: |
      {
         "name": "New Name",
         "is_default": true,
         "type": "testtype",
         "config_yaml": "verification_mode: advanced"
      }
  when: check_output_id | length > 0
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!